# How to use DISTINCT used while selecting all columns including sequence number column?

Tags: sql, oracle

My query is to avoid duplicate in a particular column while selecting all columns. But DISTINCT is not working since seq.number column is also being selected.
Any idea to make the query work
In the below example query seq_num is unique key.

Edit: including sample data in picture

```
select DISTINCT(name), seq_num from table_1;![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3NYn.jpg)
```

Comment: show the example of data that you have and what you want to have

Comment: My downvote is because you have not provided enough information to solve your problem. Specifically, include a sample of your input data and what you expect the output to be and why.

Comment: Please [don't post images](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) when you can post text. Show representative sample data, your current query and output and the desired input, all as formatted text. But your question doesn't really make sense - if `seq_num` is unique there can't be duplicate names for a `seq_num`; and if you duplicate names and only want show each of those once, then how will you decide *which* `seq_num` to show for each name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For two columns this query will be enough:

```
SELECT name, min(seq_num)
FROM table
GROUP BY name
```

For more column, use `row_number` analytic functon

```
SELECT name, col1, col2, .... col500, seq_num
FROM (
   SELECT t.*, row_number() over (partition by name order by seq_num ) As rn
   FROM table t
)
WHERE rn = 1
```

The above queries pick only one row with a given name and the smallest seq_num value for each name.

Comment: Thank you so much. It was absolutely helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do what you want. Please read more about [DISTINCT](http://psoug.org/definition/DISTINCT.htm) clause and query result set. You will understand that `distinct` is not suitable for your issue. If you provide some sample data for what you have and what should query show, when possible we will help you.

Comment: Hi... I actually wanted to eliminate duplicates and the ready made option I knew was to use DISTINCT. Thank you for clearing that there are other options to work out.